# Unioning the same table which gives 3 separate results and columns in the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, union

I have 3 select statements below each creating exactly the same computed columns, I then  count all the yes's and all the no's in that computed columns. At the moment its displaying the region 3 times with the 3 results next to it. I want it to display the region once with 3 new columns with the totals so at the moment

**I have:**

```
region1 computedCol1

region1 computedCol2

region1 computedCol3

region2 computedCol1

region2 computedCol2

region2 computedCol3
```

**I want:**

```
Region1,  computedCol1, computedCol2, computedCol3

Region2,  computedCol1, computedCol2, computedCol3

Region3,  computedCol1, computedCol2, computedCol3
```

**If I use "union all" I just get:**

```
region1 computedCol1

region2 computedCol1

region3 computedCol1
```

```
SELECT a.region, COUNT(*) AS [computedCol1]    
(
SELECT  DISTINCT table1.serial1, table1.serial2, region,
    CASE WHEN table2.serial1 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol1],
    CASE WHEN table3.serial2 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol2],
    CASE WHEN table3.serial2 IS NULL AND table2.serial1 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol3]

FROM    table1
        LEFT JOIN table2
            ON table2.serial1 = table1.serial1
        LEFT JOIN dbo.EPG
            table3.serial2 = table1.serial2
)a
    WHERE region in (
        '37000','38000','39000','41000','42000','43000','44000','46000','45000','51000','52000','53000','54000',
        '55000','56000','57000','58000','59000','61000','62000','63000','64000','65000','66000','67000','68000',
        '69000','30000','33000','36000','34000','35000','31000','32000','N/A'   )
and [CCA Match Org] in  ('no')
    GROUP BY a.region

union

SELECT b.region, COUNT(*) AS [computedCol2], region   
(
SELECT  DISTINCT table1.serial1, table1.serial2,
    CASE WHEN table2.serial1 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol1],
    CASE WHEN table3.serial2 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol2],
    CASE WHEN table3.serial2 IS NULL AND table2.serial1 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol3]

FROM    table1
        LEFT JOIN table2
            ON table2.serial1 = table1.serial1
        LEFT JOIN dbo.EPG
            table3.serial2 = table1.serial2
)b
    WHERE region in     (
        '37000','38000','39000','41000','42000','43000','44000','46000','45000','51000','52000','53000','54000'
        '55000','56000','57000','58000','59000','61000','62000','63000','64000','65000','66000','67000','68000',
        '69000','30000','33000','36000','34000','35000','31000','32000','N/A'   )
and [CCA Match Org] in ('yes')
    group by b.region

union

SELECT c.region, COUNT(*) AS [computedCol3], region   
(
SELECT  DISTINCT table1.serial1, table1.serial2,
    CASE WHEN table2.serial1 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol1],
    CASE WHEN table3.serial2 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol2],
    CASE WHEN table3.serial2 IS NULL AND table2.serial1 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol3]

FROM    table1
        LEFT JOIN table2
            ON table2.serial1 = table1.serial1
        LEFT JOIN dbo.EPG
            table3.serial2 = table1.serial2
)c
    WHERE region in     (
        '37000','38000','39000','41000','42000','43000','44000','46000','45000','51000','52000','53000','54000'
        '55000','56000','57000','58000','59000','61000','62000','63000','64000','65000','66000','67000','68000',
        '69000','30000','33000','36000','34000','35000','31000','32000','N/A'   )
and [CCA Match Org] in ('yes', 'no')
    group by c.region
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?  Later versions have `PIVOT` which will do what you are asking for.

Comment: it'll be installed on sql-server 2000

Comment: I believe `dbo.EPG` was supposed to be replaced with `table3`...

Comment: Where is `[CCA Match Org]` supposed to come from?

Answer (score 0):

That's just how UNION works in all databases. It doesn't create new columns, it contatenates all rows.

Converting rows to columns is done with the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator. In essence, PIVOT groups rows by the non-pivoted columns (Region in this case) and applies an aggregate to each of the generated columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot like the other answers suggest or you can use SUM combined with CASE to get the same result.  This becomes a pain if you have a lot of computedcols.

I'm using Oracle for my example but the concept should translate to SQLServer.

Example:

```
SELECT 'A' region, 1 col_num, 10 computed_value FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'A' region, 2 col_num, 11 computed_value FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'A' region, 3 col_num, 12 computed_value FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'B' region, 1 col_num, 20 computed_value FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'B' region, 2 col_num, 21 computed_value FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'B' region, 3 col_num, 22 computed_value FROM DUAL
```

This returns:

```
REGION  COL_NUM COMPUTED_VALUE
A           1   10
A           2   11
A           3   12
B           1   20
B           2   21
B           3   22
```

If you nest that query as follow:

```
SELECT     region,
           SUM (CASE col_num WHEN 1 THEN computed_value ELSE NULL END) compulated_1,
           SUM (CASE col_num WHEN 2 THEN computed_value ELSE NULL END) compulated_2,
           SUM (CASE col_num WHEN 3 THEN computed_value ELSE NULL END) compulated_3
    FROM   (SELECT 'A' region, 1 col_num, 10 computed_value FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT 'A' region, 2 col_num, 11 computed_value FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT 'A' region, 3 col_num, 12 computed_value FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT 'B' region, 1 col_num, 20 computed_value FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT 'B' region, 2 col_num, 21 computed_value FROM DUAL
            UNION
            SELECT 'B' region, 3 col_num, 22 computed_value FROM DUAL)
GROUP BY   region
```

Gives you:

```
REGION  COMPULATED_1    COMPULATED_2    COMPULATED_3
A           10          11           12
B           20          21           22
```

Comment: `DUAL` is Oracle and not SQL Server

Comment: @KM. I understand DUAL is Oracle and I noted that in my answer.  I used that because that's all I have access to right now and I'm only using it to build my sample data. The basic concept of using a SUM and CASE translates over to SQL Server.